# Looking glass tool for traceroute

Tags: networking, traceroute

I have used several looking glass tools from servers around the world. What I'm now looking for is a tool that will let me do what a looking glass does from my terminal. For eg. If I wanted a traceroute from looking glass X to IP Y, I'd go to X's site and run a traceroute. I want to do this from a shell script as part of a homework where several traceroutes are needed but how I get the traceroute doesnt affect my grade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from AT&T's route server at route-server.ip.att.net and many other telnet accessible route servers. Check out the category 2 route servers [here](http://www.bgp4.as/looking-glasses)

Comment: Link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, your link is not working now, [Route servers](http://www.cloudtacker.com/route-servers) are available here, including AT&T